# Cant connect to mGoogleClientApi after publishing my game on Play Store

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

My game is working just fine to me and few friends that are testers. But howerver when I published my game on Google Play Store we are not able to sign in and submit scores/ view leaderboard. We can not connect to the Google Api Client.
I have deleted my Oath2Client and added a new one but it's still not working. Please help me if you know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What error are you getting? You have not asked a question.

Comment: After we have published the game we are not able to connect to the google api client for some reason. There is no error message just the sign in button is not responding at all

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781085/google-sign-in-button-nothing-happens